# how can i get url preceding &

Tags: javascript, jquery

here i have links like this `http://www.thidiff.com/&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0ahUKEwiexM7XmaPRAhWmrVQKHUmXDXMQ_BcIYygBMBA&amp;usg=AFQjCNEf9K9tDpISjuX1qkTOHK_aeiPrwQ`

what i want is `http://www.thidiff.com/` which before `&` how it can be done

i have sample `hrefs`

```js
$('a.ganna').each(function(){
   var href = $(this).attr('href');
   var ampIndex = href.indexOf('&');
   console.log(ampIndex);
  var httIndex = href.indexOf('htt');
  console.log(httIndex);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="ganna" href="/url?q=http://www.thidiff.com/&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0ahUKEwiexM7XmaPRAhWmrVQKHUmXDXMQ_BcIYygBMBA&amp;usg=AFQjCNEf9K9tDpISjuX1qkTOHK_aeiPrwQ">Website</a>


<a class="ganna" href="/url?q=http://www.sahasraadvisoryagency.com/&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0ahUKEwjOxOnmmaPRAhUHh1QKHRR3B4cQ_BcIVCgBMA4&amp;usg=AFQjCNFIbN_BcKr1501xZcqpER22-Bfy4A">Website</a>
```

**my expected output** :

```
http://www.thidiff.com/

http://www.sahasraadvisoryagency.com/
```

Comment: @baao, please verify this `question` with that answer `it is very different question it is related cutting of matching string`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are looing for the `substr` function:

```
href.substr(httIndex, ampIndex-httIndex);
```

Working example available here:

https://jsfiddle.net/04fzt0br/

**EDIT**:
Signature of the function is : `string.substr(startIndex, length)`

Comment: thanks alot i was not knowing `substr()` working so i posted it thanks alot

Comment: what is `-` sign here indicates  `ampIndex-httIndex`  is it `minus sign`?

Comment: Yes, it is a minus sign.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do like this.

```js
$('a.ganna').each(function(){
   var href = $(this).attr('href').split('=')[1]; //splitting by `=` sign and getting 2nd element
   var domain = href.slice(0, href.indexOf('&')); //slicing string upto `&`
   console.log(domain);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.0.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="ganna" href="/url?q=http://www.thidiff.com/&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0ahUKEwiexM7XmaPRAhWmrVQKHUmXDXMQ_BcIYygBMBA&amp;usg=AFQjCNEf9K9tDpISjuX1qkTOHK_aeiPrwQ">Website</a>


<a class="ganna" href="/url?q=http://www.sahasraadvisoryagency.com/&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0ahUKEwjOxOnmmaPRAhUHh1QKHRR3B4cQ_BcIVCgBMA4&amp;usg=AFQjCNFIbN_BcKr1501xZcqpER22-Bfy4A">Website</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a regex to extract a url:

```js
var re = /http:\/\/+(www.[a-z0-9]+).com/g;
var sel = document.querySelectorAll('.ganna');

[].forEach.call(sel, function(el){
  console.log(JSON.stringify(el.href.match(re)[0], 0, 0));
})
```

```html
<a class="ganna" href="/url?q=http://www.thidiff.com/&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0ahUKEwiexM7XmaPRAhWmrVQKHUmXDXMQ_BcIYygBMBA&amp;usg=AFQjCNEf9K9tDpISjuX1qkTOHK_aeiPrwQ">Website</a>
<a class="ganna" href="/url?q=http://www.sahasraadvisoryagency.com/&amp;sa=U&amp;ved=0ahUKEwjOxOnmmaPRAhUHh1QKHRR3B4cQ_BcIVCgBMA4&amp;usg=AFQjCNFIbN_BcKr1501xZcqpER22-Bfy4A">Website</a>
```